# htmlspecialchars not working in href

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

The following code is giving me a blank url, instead of a url that I have defined in my code.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($url); ?> ">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars("<Click> visit to know more");?>
</a>
```

Comment: What does $url contain? Which of the calls to `htmlspecialchars` returns a blank url?

Comment: my url is "www.facebook.com/nokia?ref=stream&hc_location=stream"

Comment: what **$url** contien an html tags ?

Comment: use **http://** to get the correct url **http://www.facebook.com/nokia?ref=stream&hc_location=stream**

Comment: The code above with `$url = "www.facebook.com/nokia?ref=stream&hc_location=stream";` works fine for me. Although the anchor url should contain **http://** as said above to link the user to Facebook, but nothing returns a blank url.

Comment: when i click on the link it does not redirect me to the new page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/nokia?ref=stream&hc_location=stream'; ?>

<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($url); ?> ">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars("<Click> visit to know more");?>
</a>
```